# Printing multiple objects on the same line

Tags: python, function, for-loop, design-patterns

I was wondering if anyone could help me create a star pattern of letters. I want to see to have either UP or DOWN on the same line. At the moment, however, the letters are printed underneath each other rather than next on the same line. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Sample the U function:

```
def u():
    u_str = ''
    for row in range (0,7):
        for column in range (0,7):
            if (((column == 1 or column==5) and row !=6) or ((column==2 or column ==3 
               or column==4) and row==6)) :
               u_str += "*"
            else:
                u_str += " "
         u_str += "\n"
     return u_str
```

function for entering either up or down

```
def up_or_down():
    if len(user_letters) ==4 and user_letters == "DOWN":
        print(d()+o()+w()+n())
    elif len(user_letters) ==2 and user_letters == "UP":
        print(u()+p())
    else:
        pass

up_or_down()
```

Comment: Instead of the function returning a single string with all rows, return a list of rows for u, d, etc. without the newline at the end.
Then add more logic to append the rows from different letter together, and at the very end append the newline.

Comment: Please add more informations, try to give more explicit names to your variables and fucntions. Explain what you mean by "create a start pattern". Add an example of the desired output.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have six functions each with a for statement which is mandatory [U,P,D,O,W,N] . I need to use these to create either up or down images like Paime did (I thank you) but with the for statements. Once again I'm sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest that you use a `dict` to store letters ascii art, so you are not recomputing them multiple times:

```py
ascii_letters = {
    "D": d(),
    "N": n(),
    "O": o(),
    "P": p(),
    "U": u(),
    "W": w(),
}
```

Then create a function that can horizontally concatenate multilines strings:

```py
def hcat_strings(*strings):
    """`strings` must have the same number of lines"""
    # in a single line
    # return "\n".join(("  ".join(l) for l in zip(*(s.splitlines() for s in strings))))
    strings_lines = (s.splitlines() for s in strings)
    lines_as_tuples = zip(*strings_lines)
    lines = ("  ".join(l) for l in lines_as_tuples)
    return "\n".join(lines)
```

Which you can finally use as follows:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

text = "UPPUPU"
letters = itemgetter(*text)(ascii_letters)

print(hcat_strings(*letters))
```

Result:

```
*   *  *****  *****  *   *  *****  *   *
*   *  *   *  *   *  *   *  *   *  *   *
*   *  *   *  *   *  *   *  *   *  *   *
*   *  *****  *****  *   *  *****  *   *
*   *  *      *      *   *  *      *   *
*   *  *      *      *   *  *      *   *
 ***   *      *       ***   *       ***
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have six functions each with a for statement which is mandatory [U,P,D,O,W,N] . I need to use these to create either up or down images like Paime did (I thank you) but with the for statements. Once again I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yeah you do whatever you want fo the ascii art given your constraints. The real point was about the `hcat_strings` function. Can't you see you can use it the same way ? by just replacing my `letters = ...` by `letters = [d(), o(), w(), n()]`.

Comment: Btw on your `up_or_down` function, the conditions on the lengths of strings is useless.

Comment: You can also replace my `ascii_letters` dict by `ascii_letters = {"U": u(), "P": p(), "D": d() ...}` and keep the rest - it also makes more sense so you are not computing the letters again and again, but still use your function `o()`, `p()` etc.

Comment: Thank you i didn't see it before. It has been really helpful :)

Comment: If it answers your question you can accept it.

Comment: Sorry, just did now

Comment: and sorry is there any chance to get rid of the spaces in the program?

Comment: Spaces are coming from `"  ".join(l)`. You should study the code to be sure you understand it, you might learn a bit.